# wcf.cs file generated by tool

Tags: development, visual-studio, wcf

I am porting a SharePoint project from one SP 2007 server to one SP 2010 server. Among the files that make up the project, I found a file called wcf.Project.cs. It's tens-of-thousands of lines long and it was generated by a tool (though it does not say which one). I tried to haphazardly add a copy of that file to the new project solution for SP 2010, but it's giving me a hundred errors, such as invalid arguments, and zero possible resolutions. How can I find out how it was generated? If I can fix the errors, then how?